# Can not install rails on Yosemite 10.10.1 with xcode 6.3. "gem install rails -v 4.2.0" shows error on terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal, installation, rubygems, osx-yosemite

I am following the [tutorial](https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.10-yosemite) to install ruby on rails on my mac OSX Yosemite 10.10.1 , Xcode version 6.3.

Every thing goes correct till `$ ruby -v`it provides following output on terminal `ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-darwin14]` that means ruby has been installed perfectely.

I have installed the ruby. And installed Homebrew as well. But when I put `$ brew doctor` command in my terminal to check if Homebrew is working correct then it shows list of warnings.

```
Last login: Sat Apr 11 17:57:42 on ttys000
MacBook-Air:~ ankushkushwaha$ brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: Some directories in /usr/local/share/locale aren't writable.
This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed
by Homebrew. If a brew tries to add locale information to one of these
directories, then the install will fail during the link step.
You should probably `chown` them:

    /usr/local/share/locale/be
    /usr/local/share/locale/be/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/ca
    /usr/local/share/locale/ca/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/da
    /usr/local/share/locale/da/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/de
    /usr/local/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/el
    /usr/local/share/locale/el/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/es
    /usr/local/share/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/fi
    /usr/local/share/locale/fi/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/fr
    /usr/local/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/id
    /usr/local/share/locale/id/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/ja
    /usr/local/share/locale/ja/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/nl
    /usr/local/share/locale/nl/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/ru
    /usr/local/share/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/sr
    /usr/local/share/locale/sr/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/sv
    /usr/local/share/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/tr
    /usr/local/share/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/uk
    /usr/local/share/locale/uk/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/vi
    /usr/local/share/locale/vi/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/zh_CN
    /usr/local/share/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/zh_TW
    /usr/local/share/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES

Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
    /usr/local/lib/libgcc_ext.10.4.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libgcc_ext.10.5.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libgfortran.3.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libgomp.1.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libquadmath.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libssp.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib

Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/backward/auto_ptr.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/backward/backward_warning.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/backward/binders.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/backward/hash_fun.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/backward/hashtable.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/algorithmfwd.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/allocator.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/atomic_0.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/atomic_2.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/atomic_base.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/basic_ios.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/basic_string.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/boost_concept_check.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/c++0x_warning.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/char_traits.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/codecvt.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/concept_check.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/cpp_type_traits.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/cxxabi_forced.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/exception_defines.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/exception_ptr.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/forward_list.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/functexcept.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/functional_hash.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/gslice.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/gslice_array.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/hash_bytes.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/hashtable.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/hashtable_policy.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/indirect_array.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/ios_base.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/locale_classes.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/locale_facets.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/locale_facets_nonio.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/localefwd.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/mask_array.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/move.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/nested_exception.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/ostream_insert.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/postypes.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/random.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/range_access.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/regex.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/regex_compiler.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/regex_constants.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/regex_cursor.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/regex_error.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/regex_grep_matcher.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/regex_nfa.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/shared_ptr.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/shared_ptr_base.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/slice_array.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/stl_algo.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/stl_algobase.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/stl_bvector.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/stl_construct.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/stl_deque.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/stl_function.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/stl_heap.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/stl_iterator.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/stl_iterator_base_funcs.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/stl_list.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/stl_map.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/stl_multimap.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/stl_multiset.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/stl_numeric.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/stl_pair.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/stl_queue.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/stl_raw_storage_iter.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/stl_relops.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/stl_set.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/stl_stack.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/stl_tempbuf.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/stl_tree.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/stl_vector.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/stream_iterator.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/streambuf_iterator.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/stringfwd.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/unique_ptr.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/unordered_map.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/unordered_set.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/valarray_after.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/valarray_array.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/bits/valarray_before.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/complex.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/cxxabi.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/debug/debug.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/debug/formatter.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/debug/functions.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/debug/macros.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/debug/map.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/debug/multimap.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/debug/multiset.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/debug/safe_base.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/debug/safe_iterator.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/debug/safe_sequence.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/debug/set.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/decimal/decimal.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/ext/array_allocator.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/ext/atomicity.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/ext/bitmap_allocator.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/ext/cast.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/ext/codecvt_specializations.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/ext/concurrence.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/ext/debug_allocator.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/ext/enc_filebuf.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/ext/extptr_allocator.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/ext/malloc_allocator.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/ext/mt_allocator.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/ext/new_allocator.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/ext/numeric_traits.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/ext/pod_char_traits.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/ext/pointer.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/ext/pool_allocator.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/ext/rc_string_base.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/ext/ropeimpl.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/ext/sso_string_base.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/ext/stdio_filebuf.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/ext/stdio_sync_filebuf.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/ext/string_conversions.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/ext/throw_allocator.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/ext/type_traits.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/ext/typelist.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/ext/vstring.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/ext/vstring_fwd.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/ext/vstring_util.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/fenv.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/parallel/algo.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/parallel/algobase.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/parallel/algorithmfwd.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/parallel/balanced_quicksort.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/parallel/base.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/parallel/basic_iterator.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/parallel/checkers.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/parallel/compatibility.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/parallel/compiletime_settings.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/parallel/equally_split.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/parallel/features.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/parallel/find.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/parallel/find_selectors.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/parallel/for_each.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/parallel/for_each_selectors.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/parallel/iterator.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/parallel/list_partition.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/parallel/losertree.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/parallel/merge.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/parallel/multiseq_selection.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/parallel/multiway_merge.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/parallel/multiway_mergesort.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/parallel/numericfwd.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/parallel/omp_loop.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/parallel/omp_loop_static.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/parallel/par_loop.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/parallel/parallel.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/parallel/partial_sum.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/parallel/partition.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/parallel/queue.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/parallel/quicksort.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/parallel/random_number.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/parallel/random_shuffle.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/parallel/search.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/parallel/set_operations.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/parallel/settings.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/parallel/sort.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/parallel/tags.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/parallel/types.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/parallel/unique_copy.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/parallel/workstealing.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/profile/base.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/profile/impl/profiler.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/profile/impl/profiler_algos.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/profile/impl/profiler_container_size.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/profile/impl/profiler_hash_func.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/profile/impl/profiler_hashtable_size.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/profile/impl/profiler_list_to_slist.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/profile/impl/profiler_list_to_vector.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/profile/impl/profiler_map_to_unordered_map.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/profile/impl/profiler_node.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/profile/impl/profiler_state.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/profile/impl/profiler_trace.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/profile/impl/profiler_vector_size.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/profile/impl/profiler_vector_to_list.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/profile/iterator_tracker.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/profile/map.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/profile/multimap.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/profile/multiset.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/profile/set.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/tgmath.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/tr1/complex.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/tr1/ctype.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/tr1/fenv.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/tr1/float.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/tr1/functional_hash.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/tr1/hashtable.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/tr1/hashtable_policy.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/tr1/inttypes.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/tr1/limits.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/tr1/math.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/tr1/random.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/tr1/shared_ptr.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/tr1/special_function_util.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/tr1/stdarg.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/tr1/stdbool.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/tr1/stdint.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/tr1/stdio.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/tr1/stdlib.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/tr1/tgmath.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/tr1/unordered_map.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/tr1/unordered_set.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/tr1/wchar.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/tr1/wctype.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/bits/atomic_word.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/bits/basic_file.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/bits/c++allocator.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/bits/c++config.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/bits/c++io.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/bits/c++locale.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/bits/cpu_defines.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/bits/ctype_base.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/bits/ctype_inline.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/bits/ctype_noninline.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/bits/cxxabi_tweaks.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/bits/error_constants.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/bits/extc++.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/bits/gthr-default.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/bits/gthr-posix.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/bits/gthr-single.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/bits/gthr-tpf.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/bits/gthr.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/bits/messages_members.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/bits/os_defines.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/bits/stdc++.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/bits/stdtr1c++.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/bits/time_members.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/i386/bits/atomic_word.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/i386/bits/basic_file.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/i386/bits/c++allocator.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/i386/bits/c++config.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/i386/bits/c++io.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/i386/bits/c++locale.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/i386/bits/cpu_defines.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/i386/bits/ctype_base.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/i386/bits/ctype_inline.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/i386/bits/ctype_noninline.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/i386/bits/cxxabi_tweaks.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/i386/bits/error_constants.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/i386/bits/extc++.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/i386/bits/gthr-default.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/i386/bits/gthr-posix.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/i386/bits/gthr-single.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/i386/bits/gthr-tpf.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/i386/bits/gthr.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/i386/bits/messages_members.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/i386/bits/os_defines.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/i386/bits/stdc++.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/i386/bits/stdtr1c++.h
    /usr/local/include/c++/4.6.0/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/i386/bits/time_members.h
    /usr/local/include/gmp.h
    /usr/local/include/mpc.h
    /usr/local/include/mpf2mpfr.h
    /usr/local/include/mpfr.h

Warning: Unbrewed .la files were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .la files:
    /usr/local/lib/libgfortran.la
    /usr/local/lib/libgmp.la
    /usr/local/lib/libgomp.la
    /usr/local/lib/libmpc.la
    /usr/local/lib/libmpfr.la
    /usr/local/lib/libquadmath.la
    /usr/local/lib/libssp.la
    /usr/local/lib/libssp_nonshared.la
    /usr/local/lib/libstdc++.la
    /usr/local/lib/libsupc++.la

Warning: Unbrewed static libraries were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected static libraries:
    /usr/local/lib/libgfortran.a
    /usr/local/lib/libgmp.a
    /usr/local/lib/libgomp.a
    /usr/local/lib/libiberty.a
    /usr/local/lib/libmpc.a
    /usr/local/lib/libmpfr.a
    /usr/local/lib/libquadmath.a
    /usr/local/lib/libssp.a
    /usr/local/lib/libssp_nonshared.a
    /usr/local/lib/libstdc++.a
    /usr/local/lib/libsupc++.a
```

After searching on google I found that these warning has nothing to do with installation process for ruby on rails (I guess so :/). Then I put `$ gem install rails -v 4.2.0` This command shows following error on terminal

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/ankushkushwaha/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150411-31116-lxsk7p.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... yes
checking for iconv... yes
************************************************************************
IMPORTANT NOTICE:

Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxml2-2.9.2
with the following patches applied:
    - 0001-Revert-Missing-initialization-for-the-catalog-module.patch
    - 0002-Fix-missing-entities-after-CVE-2014-3660-fix.patch

Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security
updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want
to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and
reinstall nokogiri as follows:

    gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
        [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
        [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

    bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install

Note, however, that nokogiri is not fully compatible with arbitrary
versions of libxml2 provided by OS/package vendors.
************************************************************************
Extracting libxml2-2.9.2.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/ports/libxml2/2.9.2... OK
Running patch with /Users/ankushkushwaha/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxml2/0001-Revert-Missing-initialization-for-the-catalog-module.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxml2 2.9.2... OK
Running patch with /Users/ankushkushwaha/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxml2/0002-Fix-missing-entities-after-CVE-2014-3660-fix.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxml2 2.9.2... OK
Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.9.2... ERROR, review '/Users/ankushkushwaha/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ext/nokogiri/tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/ports/libxml2/2.9.2/configure.log' to see what happened.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/ankushkushwaha/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --enable-static
    --disable-static
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --enable-cross-build
    --disable-cross-build
/Users/ankushkushwaha/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mini_portile-0.6.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:279:in `block in execute': Failed to complete configure task (RuntimeError)
    from /Users/ankushkushwaha/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mini_portile-0.6.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:271:in `chdir'
    from /Users/ankushkushwaha/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mini_portile-0.6.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:271:in `execute'
    from /Users/ankushkushwaha/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mini_portile-0.6.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:66:in `configure'
    from /Users/ankushkushwaha/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mini_portile-0.6.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:109:in `cook'
    from extconf.rb:278:in `block in process_recipe'
    from extconf.rb:177:in `tap'
    from extconf.rb:177:in `process_recipe'
    from extconf.rb:475:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/ankushkushwaha/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/ankushkushwaha/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/gem_make.out
```

I have Xcode6.3 and command line tool installed as well. I am not able to get why this error is persisting. I am new on ruby on rails and just want to learn this technology. This is my first time I am installing it on my mac. I am newbie. Please guys if anyone can help me in this case I will really be thankful from the bottom of my heart :).
The guy doing same thing in this [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zCSoVeJhRU0) is getting no error.

**PS**: When I started following the tutorial to install ruby on rails then I had xcode 6.1. And I had installed command line tool on xcode 6.1. After that I saw this error and updated my xcode from 6.1 to 6.3. I have also installed the command line tool for xcode6.3 again from apple website. I thought this error is because of xcode 6.1 but It is of no use. :(

Comment: https://github.com/ruhoh/ruhoh.rb/issues/267#issuecomment-83506638 & https://github.com/ruhoh/ruhoh.rb/issues/267#issuecomment-86230775 could be helpful.

Comment: Not working. I am not able to install some gems

Comment: anything interesting in `/Users/ankushkushwaha/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ext/nokogiri/tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/ports/libxml2/2.9.2/configure.log` ?

Comment: No I guess. Here it is

https://www.dropbox.com/s/cmja4wa1xu0gnwo/Screen%20Shot%202015-04-11%20at%207.55.43%20pm.png?dl=0

Comment: It halts on "Checking weather C complier works"

Comment: I am getting this error in console.log  when I enter some random commands--> This checking for x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0-gcc... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/ankushkushwaha/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ext/nokogiri/tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/ports/libxml2/2.9.2/libxml2-2.9.2':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details